# Create/alter a dataframe based on another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two dataframes as below

Inp1

```
Col1  col2
10     usd,hkg
20     tst, fds
30     hgf, usd
```

Inp2

```
X_col1  x_col2
200      usd
100      hkg
250      tst
280      fds
```

.... So on

I want to loop up my Inp2 dataframe using the col2 from Inp1 to achieve the below output

```
Out
Col1  tot  col2
10    300  usd,hkg
20    530  tst,fds
```

And so on.
Pls help on how to achieve this

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You seem to have a combination of join, groupby, and sum.  All of these are covered in PANDAS tutorials, so we expect to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Split `df1['col2']` then explode. This allows us to generate a unique merge key.

```
>>> df1['col2'] = df1['col2'].str.split(r',\s*')
>>> df1

   Col1        col2
0    10  [usd, hkg]
1    20  [tst, fds]
2    30  [hgf, usd]

>>> df1.explode('col2')

   Col1 col2
0    10  usd
0    10  hkg
1    20  tst
1    20  fds
2    30  hgf
2    30  usd
```

After merging, you can then get the quantities in the second input frame.

```
>>> m = df1.explode('col2').merge(df2, left_on='col2', right_on='x_col2', how='left')
>>> m

   Col1 col2  X_col1 x_col2
0    10  usd   200.0    usd
1    10  hkg   100.0    hkg
2    20  tst   250.0    tst
3    20  fds   280.0    fds
4    30  hgf     NaN    NaN
5    30  usd   200.0    usd
```

Assigning them to `m`, then set up for the data to be attached to a new data frame `df1_m` on a `Col1` index (assuming that `Col1` values are unique). Then sum across those values. I have no idea why your desired input doesn't contain one of the matching pairs, but if you don't want it, you can discard it by dropping where `df['Col1'] == 30`.

```
>>> df1_m = df1.set_index('Col1')
>>> df1_m['sum'] = m.groupby('Col1')['X_col1'].sum()
>>> df1_m.reset_index()

   Col1        col2    sum
0    10  [usd, hkg]  300.0
1    20  [tst, fds]  530.0
2    30  [hgf, usd]  200.0
```